# How to use contain in my queryset that use JSONField in my django model

Tags: python, json, django

I have this JSONField in my django model :

```
{
    "site-acces": {
        "title": "digimon",
        "compare": {
            "with": "sagromon",
        }
    },
  "site-denied": {
        "title": "pokemon",
        "compare": {
            "with": "salameche",
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do a query in django that do that :
search into my Json all object with title that contain "pokemon".

I tried that :

```
pokemon.filter(widgets__contains={'title': 'pokemon'})
```

but it's not working... That return me empty queryset.
So i also tried that:

```
pokemon.filter(widgets__title= 'pokemon')
```

but not working too. I think that not working because the "title" meta is inside "site-denied" ...

So i'm asking how can i search a string inside this "site-denied". But take care ! It's not always "site-denied", some times that could be "site-acces", or other random string. So i can't do a search using "site-denied" word.

Answer (score 1):

If only two keys are possible, use Q *or* expression:

```
from django.db.models import Q

pokemon.filter(
    Q(**{'widget__site-acces__title__contains': 'pokemon'}) | 
    Q(**{'widget__site-denied__title__contains': 'pokemon'})
)
```

If you dont know all possible keys, consider storing titles in a different structure.

Comment: I have more than 2 keys possible. that could be something else

Comment: If you dont want to change the structure, you may need to go on raw SQL level to make it work, I wouldnt expect django ORM to be able to solve your issue (assuming you're using Postgresql). If you want to use raw sql, its possible to achieve what you want with jsonb_each function.